# Use SmartPhone NFC as Access Control identifier

Tags: android, windows-phone-8, nfc, smartphone, hce

We have a rather large management system and are looking to extend it with a door access control system, getting that to Work with some mifare cards is pretty straigtforward.

However alot of smartphones already have an NFC chip that could be read as well and used for identification.

My goal would be that the user should simply be able to open the door with their phone.
They should not need to turn on their phone, so iam thinking i would need to emulate a passive Card, is this at all possible without the phone being on?

I know android now supports HCE, but is that the right thing to use for this purpose?
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html

And how would you do this on Windows Phones that also have an NFC chip?

Comment: The phone would need to be on, even with Android, as it routes thru the CPU.

Comment: And Windows Phone 8 doesn't currently have an exposed API for HCE.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, HCE can be used to this purpose. Note that you will be able to separate HCE devices from desfire cards, however if you want to use the same protocol as defire cards, you'd have to implement quite a bit of logic on the devices themselves. So you might want to go with something more simple in that case.

Comment: Do you know if the phone needs to be on as WiredPrairie says?